# Has anyone created an RDBMS database for NOAA weather data?

Tags: noaa

We are interested in the weather data published by NOAA via Data.gov The site offers the ability to download data as PDF or CSV files. Has anyone created a real RDBMS (MySQL, SQLite) database out of the data? Is that available as an open-source resource?

Comment: If you're referring to the ISD data (https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/isd), it wouldn't be hard to create such a db, but it would be very large, I've gotten SQLite to handle 6M rows in geonames (http://geonames.db.94y.info/), but I think ISD would be too much. I'd offer to create a db for you, but, if you already have the data, it's a lot more efficient to do it yourself.

Comment: @BarryCarter I was trying to avoid having to write code and create this DB myself.

Comment: fair enough, but since the data is already in machine-readable form, and is really large, I don't see anyone releasing an SQL version of it (CSV is sort of the default way of releasing things).

Comment: My https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/WEATHER/bc-parse-ghcnd.pl may or may not be helpful, but it's GHCND data, not ISD.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/noaa-gsod may be helpful-- it appears Google BigQuery is really into taking public data sets and converting them to SQL. It also appears one of their sample queries, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/public-data/noaa-gsod#the_warmest_day_in_2015_in_the_us_by_state claims it was nearly 130F in Alaska in 2015.